# Having an HTML table, how can I toggle between displaying only specific rows using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a little bit help with my HTML/CSS and JavaScript for a certain task. So, let's say I have built a website and I have a accumulated a bunch of blog posts that I listed in a table with links to the complete articles. Now, I want to filter by category. E.g., that only articles that were written in 2013 are displayed when I click a "2013" button.

Right now, I am doing it the "dumb" way, where I create a separate HTML file for every category. But I thought that there might be a cleverer way to not generate separate HTML files, but via tagging table rows and only displaying certain ones upon a "click" event.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Below is an example screenshot to explain the issue more visually, and below the image is some example HTML code of how my blog table is currently formatted.

[image]

I really appreciate any sort of idea and suggestion!

```
<table class="table_blog">
        <tr onclick="location.href='link_to_article.html'">
                <td>
                    <img src="article_image" alt="">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="header">Article title</div>
                    <div class="date">-- date article was written</div>
                    <div class="abstract">abstract for the article</div>
                </td>
        </tr>
         <tr onclick="location.href='link_to_article.html'">
                <td>
                    <img src="article_image" alt="">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="header">Article title</div>
                    <div class="date">-- date article was written</div>
                    <div class="abstract">abstract for the article</div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="location.href='link_to_article.html'">
                <td>
                    <img src="article_image" alt="">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="header">Article title</div>
                    <div class="date">-- date article was written</div>
                    <div class="abstract">abstract for the article</div>
                </td>
        </tr>
[...]
```

Comment: You can definitely do this, and the process you described (tagging, click events, etc.) is a reasonable way to go about it.  Have you tried to implement it?  It should be pretty simple to do, give it a shot and if you run into a specific issue post it, but you'll have better luck here if you have some code to show.  Just googling this would probably turn up plenty of results or guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will filter out any records that are not equal to a given publish year.

Adding the following HTML above your table:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:filterArticles('2014');">2014</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:filterArticles('2013');">2013</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:filterArticles('2012');">2012</a>
```

Then adding the following javascript to your page will yield filtered rows as you request.

```
function filterArticles(yearFilter){
    $(".table_blog div[class='date']").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == yearFilter){
            $(this).closest("tr").show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest("tr").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Please see this working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YmApX/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a simple solution and yet it works perfectly well for what I wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

insert some classes in your table rows and use javascript to show/hide them

```
<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        $("#year2013").click(function(){
            $("tr").hide();
            $(".2013").show();
        });
    });
</script>
<button type="button" id="year2013">2013</button>
<table class="table_blog">
    <tr class="2013 goodies health" onclick="location.href='link_to_article.html'">
            <td>
                <img src="article_image" alt="">
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="header">Article title</div>
                <div class="date">-- date article was written</div>
                <div class="abstract">abstract for the article</div>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2013 professional" onclick="location.href='link_to_article.html'">
            <td>
                <img src="article_image" alt="">
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="header">Article title</div>
                <div class="date">-- date article was written</div>
                <div class="abstract">abstract for the article</div>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2014 health kitchen" onclick="location.href='link_to_article.html'">
            <td>
                <img src="article_image" alt="">
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="header">Article title</div>
                <div class="date">-- date article was written</div>
                <div class="abstract">abstract for the article</div>
            </td>
    </tr>
    [...]
```

This is just an example, though. Anyway, i think it is better to be made in the server side

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use divs instead of a table to lay out your articles. This is considered best practice in modern web development.

To answer your question directly, this can be accomplished using the CSS display property. Create a CSS class like so:

```
.hidden-article{
   display:none;
}
```

To hide something, give it that CSS class. To display it, remove the CSS class. To do this dynamically (without reloading the page), you need to use JavaScript. I recommend using a library like jQuery. It's very lightweight and helps with DOM manipulation.

Additionally, jQuery makes this task very simple. It has a [hide method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) in addition to providing things like handlers for when people click on elements (like say your hyperlinks) and tying them to JavaScript functions you write.

In order to figure out which elements to show or hide, you may have to do some work in JavaScript to parse the date out. jQuery will help you get the date out of those elements that are  if you're not storing the underlying data already in JavaScript. Once you get the text of the date extracted you're going to need to convert it to a date and do some comparisons. I recommend the excellent [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to make working with dates a snap in JavaScript.